# An easy to use package for hp-FEM?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Can anyone point me towards an easy to use implementation of state of the art hp-FEM for solving 2d elliptic BVPs? Preferably in python or matlab.

Comment: Please be more specific. Most FEM packages are application oriented, such as "structural mechanics" or " fluid flow". Are your Boundary Value Problems linear or non-linear, for example? And what do you mean by high performance? How big are your problems? And how big is your budget? 2-D only does not have a big market share, I think, and it does not appear demanding w.r.t. computer resources. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Lets say I want to deal with the most basic question of Laplace on a polygon with a small (<10) number of sides.